# Navigation property with additional constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm new to EF and CodeFirst and I have the following (simplified) Models:

```
public class Comment
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public int SourceType {get; set;}
    public int SourceID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Text {get; set;}
}

public class Photo
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments {get; set;}
}

public class BlogPost
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments {get; set;}
}
```

And in my actual database I have only thos three tables.
My goal is to have a table "comments" which stores comments users post for photos as well as for blog posts. The `Comment.SourceType` field should distinguish between a comment posted to a photo (SourceType==1) or a blog post (SourceType==2), while the `Comment.SourceID` field tells me the ID of the source.

```
Photo photo = DbContext.Photos.Find(15); //some photo with ID 15
BlogPost blog = DbContext.BlogPost.Find(15); //some blog post, also with ID 15

Comment photoComment = new Comment();
photoComment.SourceType = 1; //photo
photoComment.SourceID = photo.ID;
photoComment.Name = "John";
photoComment.Text = "This is a very nice picture!";

Comment blogComment = new Comment();
blogComment.SourceType = 2; //blog post
blogComment.SourceID = blog.ID;
blogComment.Name = "Peter";
blogComment.Text = "An interesting blog post!";

DbContext.Comments.Add(photoComment);
DbContext.Comments.Add(blogComment);
DbContext.SaveChanges();

//...

Photo photoFromBefore = DbContext.Photos.Find(15);
foreach(Comment comment in photoFromBefore.Comments)
    Console.Write(comment.Name+"("+comment.SourceType+", "+comment.SourceID+"); ");
//Output will be: "John(1, 15); Peter(2, 15);"
//Desired output should be instead just "John(1, 15);"
//because Peter's comment actually belongs to blog post with
//the same ID but different "SourceType"-identifier in my database table.
```

I hope it's somehow clear what I'm trying to achieve. Basically, I don't want to have multiple tables `photo_comments`, `blogpost_comments` etc. for everything that can be commented on my website.

Can I somehow tell EF to load only the comments with `SourceType==1` (for photos)? Is there some type of "constraint" or "restriction" I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a LINQ where clause in your foreach statement.

```
foreach(Comment comment in photoFromBefore.Comments.Where(x=>x.SourceType == 2))
```

Also, looking at the code, should the line above the foreach be

```
IEnumerable<Photo> photoFromBefore = DbContext.Photos.First(15);
```

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid though :) The whole purpose of EF is to do less work. I know I can load the comments by hand but `Photo.Comments` is a navigation property that lazy loads all of that Photo's comments automatically when I call it.
Also, you were right about the incorrect code. I had a typo ("First" instead of "Find") which I corrected now. Thanks.

Comment: Your issue is going to be that photos and blogs are two different tables (right?).  Since they are two different tables, they are going to have two sets of primary keys.  So - you can have a blog with Id 1 and a photo with Id 1.  There is no way for EF to know which comment to load based on that Id without specifying a where clause in your Find statement (sourcetype == x).  A navigation property is a code equivalent of a FK - you have the value mapped from table a col x to table b col y. If you are trying to avoid a where clause, you could store the source type in your photo and blog tables...

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the problem :) I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to make EF _know_ which comment to load. For example with the Fluid API. Override `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` with something like `modelBuilder.Entity<Photo>().Property(p => p.Comments).HasCondition(c => c.SourceType == 1);` and `modelBuilder.Entity<BlogPost>().Property(b => b.Comments).HasCondition(c => c.SourceType == 2);`. I'm just spitballing here but I'm wondering if something like this is possible?